# In Android given a file not stored in MediaStore, how to find if it is audio or video file?

Tags: android

Given a file path how do we find out if it is audio or video file ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String fileExtension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
```

This will give you "jpg" or "mp4".  You'll just have to have some sort of collection of filetypes to check against.